# Visual Studio 2022 build error building xamarin.android project

Tags: android, xamarin, build

```
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024: System.IO.IOException: Ошибка в данных (CRC).
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024: 
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024:    at System.IO.FileStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024:    at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024:    at System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Stream inputStream)
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024:    at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.Files.HashFile(String filename, HashAlgorithm hashAlg) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/Files.cs:line 438
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024:    at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.Files.HashFile(String filename) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/Files.cs:line 432
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(IDictionary`2 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments, ICollection`1 proguardConfigFiles)
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.RunTask()
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.EmbeddedResource.targets(36,5): error XARLP7024:    at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17
```

Try clean bin/obj folders, rebuild - no result.

Comment: Did these errors appear during the default Xamarin.android project running ?